# How do you get a program to pick a different string from a list each time rather than writing the same string over and over again?

Tags: c#, list

I am having an issue with picking randomly from a list. When I run the program, it keeps writing the same string over and over again when I want it to come up with a different random string each time. Here is an example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace List
{

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    var letterList = new List<string>
        {
            "A","B","C","D"
        };

    Random r = new Random();

    int letterListIndex = r.Next(letterList.Count);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        Console.WriteLine(letterList[letterListIndex]);

    }
 }
}
}
```

For Example: When I run this code it would write "B" 10 times. I want it to come up with 10 different letters every time. I know that you could just write:

```
int letterListIndex1 = r.Next(letterList.Count);
int letterListIndex2 = r.Next(letterList.Count);
int letterListIndex3 = r.Next(letterList.Count);

Console.WriteLine(letterList[letterListIndex1]);
Console.WriteLine(letterList[letterListIndex2]);
Console.WriteLine(letterList[letterListIndex3]);
```

But I wanted to know if there was an easier way to do so.

Thanks.

Comment: Move `int letterListIndex = r.Next(letterList.Count);` to _inside_ the loop. Otherwise, you use the same index over and over.

Comment: TBH you don't even need that var, just use `Console.WriteLine(letterList[r.Next(letterList.Count)]);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should put your `letterListIndex` variable inside `for` loop

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int letterListIndex = r.Next(letterList.Count);
    Console.WriteLine(letterList[letterListIndex]);
}
```

Otherwise you get the same index every time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put

```
int letterListIndex = r.Next(letterList.Count);
```

inside the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Console.WriteLine(letterList[r.Next(letterList.Count)]);
}
```